# Customer Support Identifier-How to get this?

Tags: oracle

I was trying to create an account in this site which gives you complete functional implementation of the Oracle Applications 11i ( http://vis11510.solutionbeacon.net/OA_HTML/AppsLocalLogin.jsp?requestUrl=APPSHOMEPAGE&cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fvis11510.solutionbeacon.net%3A80%2Foa_servlets%2Foracle.apps.fnd.sso.AppsLogin ) . The site asks me to provide Oracle CSI (Customer Support Identifier) any idea how i can

Customer Support Identifier (CSI) numberd through Oracle Support?

Answer (score 2):

You need to buy an Oracle license.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain CSI without buying any oracle product

Comment: I can't tell you about CSI but you buy Oracle the same way you buy other software: visit their site and follow the links ;-) However, Oracle is a corporate app that's very expensive. How exactly did you reach the conclusion that you need that CSI thingy?

Comment: The provider's registration states "In order for Solution Beacon to be able to continue to provide Vision environments for public use, Oracle now requires us to ask for a Customer Support Identifier (CSI) number which can be obtained through Oracle Support. "

Comment: Well, I just don't think they'll give you a customer ID unless you become a customer.